# php foreach result it's own page?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, foreach, pagination

I am building a quiz and I would like to have each page be it's own question, and when the user selects an answer, he gets feedback on if he was correct or not before proceeding to the next question. At the end of the quiz, I want to show their answers in summary.

There is not specific number of question to each quiz, so I need to find a way to know when to finish the quiz.

My thoughts so far are :

1 - count the number of questions in the database -> save to global[num_question]

2 - create counter variable that increments each time a user answers a question

3 - some if logic for when the counter is 0, finish the quiz and display a summary.

Am I overthinking this? I am using codeigniter if that helps

Comment: If you start with this you got a tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psQKo3TCPhk about the summary try use ajax post the get the response header content to json with an request mysql gave you an array and you have to change the array to json simple json_encode($result_array_from_mysql) you got a object json in the param of the ajax function anonymous is the return of php response do what you need with to make you summary parsing the page without any refresh, regards.

Comment: Depends on the number of questions but as a general an SQL COUNT() is pretty quick, you can run that when necessary to find out if you are at the end of the set of questions. Another thing to look at is using the $_SESSION variable to store variables across different page loads